# How can I access the .zip file ML.NET creates, when I'm publishing to Google Cloud?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-cloud-platform, ml.net

I am building a Car Management Web API, and in order to get an average price for a car I have built a model using ML.NET and, as expected, it has created a .zip file where the training data is. Now everything works as expected locally. The problem is, even though I have pointed to the file with a relative path, I get an error on Google Cloud saying that the file cannot be found.

When running the app locally, I can access the endpoint, and everything works. This is how I've loaded the model

```
Model.Load("../CarManagementAPIML.Model/MLModel.zip", out var modelInputSchema);
```

On Google Cloud however I'm getting this error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/CarManagementAPIML.Model/MLModel.zip'.
at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open
```

I'm thinking that since the app is published, the folder structure is lost. So I sould have to place the file somewhere else. I have uploaded it into a bucket, but I have no idea how to call it, and even if that would actually work.
What could I do?

Thank you!

Comment: "even though I have pointed to the file with a relative path" - relative to what? I suspect the problem is that it's *trying* to load the file relative to your process's current working directory, but you *want* to load it relative to some aspect of your web application (e.g. the content root). I'd *start* by specifying an absolute filename to check that that works, and then work out how to get the right "root" directory to provide a relative path to.

Comment: (It's not obvious to me how you *are* deploying the application, by the way. It would help if you could provide more information about that. I doubt that it's running directly from a GCS bucket, for example...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to have been much easier that I first thought.

I had to add a PreditionEnginePool with the models, and have the .zip inside the start point of the api.

Very good explanation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

Everything works now.